# Cambiar una imagen al hacer clic con Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Estoy tratando de cambiar una imagen usando Angular pero no logro que me funcione, me carga la imagen inicial pero al hacer clic no logro cambiarla. Acá les dejo mi código para que me ayuden

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav',
  templateUrl: './nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav.component.css']
})
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  image = 'assets/images/iconos/presentacion.png';

  constructor() {
   }

   functionChangeImage(image: any) {
    this.image = image.src;
    this.image = (image.src === this.image) ?
    this.image = 'assets/images/iconos/presentacion-activo.png' : this.image;
    console.log(this.image);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Este es el fragmento del código HTML donde hago uso de la función

```
<img (click)="functionChangeImage($event.target)" [src]="image" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solo quieres que se cambie la imagen al darle clic bastaría con esto:

```
functionChangeImage() {
   this.image = 'assets/images/iconos/presentacion-activo.png'
 }
```